# $http post call hangs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, post

I am trying to create a page to display all the forum posts...everything works fine, but I notice that after I create a post (when it redirects to show all of the posts) - in firebug, the post call hangs for a very long time. However, the data gets sent through, even though it looks like the post call is still pending...because it shows up on the page with all of the posts, that gets loaded right after. This is how I am doing it now.

post controller (post.js):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appApp')
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($location, $scope, $http) {
  $scope.errors = {};
  $scope.post;

  $scope.postit = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;

    if(form.$valid) {
        console.log($scope.post.posttitle + " this is $scope.post");
        $http.post('/api/post', $scope.post).success(function() {console.log("no errors whoohoo")});
        $location.path('/forum');
    }
  };
});
```

As you can see, right now, I am executing the redirect (`$location.path`) after the post call line. The redirect works fine like this...however - if I try to put the redirect in the `success` function:

```
$http.post('/api/post', $scope.post).success(function() {$location.path('/forum'); console.log("no errors whoohoo")});
```

the redirect never happens, and it just hangs on the post call. Does anyone know what is going on? I think the post call should only take a few ms to complete (it is just storing a post title, and content).

The post call hangs regardless of which way I do it...it's just the second way doesn't redirect the page.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments, something is wrong with my server side code - I may have isolated the problem.

This is the function that gets called when I want to list all the posts on the page (api.js):

```
exports.posts = function(req, res) {
  return Post.find(function (err, posts) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(posts + " server side posts function route");
      return res.json(posts);
    } else {
      return res.send(err);
    }
  });
};
```

The `console.log` message never appears, so this must be where it is getting hung up...any ideas?

The area of code that calls this function looks like this:

```
app.route('/api/post')
    .get(api.posts);
```

It is one of my express routes.

Comment: Have you tried to use .then rather then .success? In the top example does it log "no errors whoohoo"

Comment: @JaredReeves just tried it - still hanging.

Comment: @JaredReeves - the message doesnt get logged either...

Comment: If it is not getting into the success callback it means that the $http is likely failing. Are you sure that the api is returning anything

Comment: I just tried your code on my local server and it works great. Can you double check if you defined your routes correctly for /forum ?

Comment: to confirm with jared, is the log displayed when $location.path is outside your success event or the log does not display in both cases but your post(title, content) are inserted to the database ?

Comment: Have you tried putting http error handler too?

Comment: I haven't tried logging outside the success function...but the redirect works outside...so I'm assuming a log would too - all my naming looks correct

Comment: @Nilesh How would I set up the error handler?

Comment: @Nilesh I did this: `$http.post('/api/post', $scope.post).success(function() {console.log("no errors whoohoo")}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {console.log(data)});` and nothing is logged.

Comment: @Nilesh - all that is happening that is making me wonder about this is that a little rotating progress thing pops up next to the post call in firebug...and it doesn't stop - and im pretty sure it's status is `pending`

Comment: One thing I'm thinking is...when it redirects...it makes a `get` request to the same route in express (`/api/post`) because it needs to do that to load the forum posts to display them...could the get request be happening before the post request finishes?

Comment: I just tried renaming the route to `api/post/list` to see if i was on the right track...and it still has the same problem.

Comment: I took out the redirect (`location.path`) completely and it is still hanging - something is happening in the request...I also restarted my computer and tried it but still not working.

Comment: I am not sure if relative path without using <base> tag works with $http. Also can you try to make the same call using either soapui or curl. Just make sure there is no problem on the server side.

Comment: @Nilesh what do you mean by "<base> tag"? - how would i go about doing curl check?

Comment: <base> tag is html5 tag for specifying default base url for all relative urls used in the page. Curl is just one way of making sure the api endpoint is working as expected & there are no firewall/server issues. See this: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: @Nilesh I ran `curl --request POST http://localhost:9000/api/post/list` in my console...and it just hangs and there is no output...

Comment: @Nilesh I also noticed while trying to get the delete functionality for the posts correct...that it also hangs in the same way when I try a DELETE request...i am using mongo - could it be related to anything there?

Comment: That means issue is not with angular code. Probably some issue on the server side. May be the resource you try to access is protected? Update your question with the piece of server side code that you think might be failing & someone might help you.

Comment: @Nilesh - i posted some server side code - please take a look if you can - i think i isolated where the problem is.

Comment: @Nilesh - also  `curl --request DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/post/delete/[number of valid id]` worked when i did it in the terminal right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using `$location.path('/xxx')` wasn't enough, I needed to also use `res.redirect` on the express side for the redirect to actually work. (Had to use both).